# Hibernate batch delete

Tags: database, hibernate

So I retrieved a List of objects directly from my database and wish to delete them. However, from the docs, it looks like I have to construct the entire SQL query in a string, and pass that string to the createQuery method in order to delete. Isn't there a better way to do it?

```
    List<Foo> confirm = (List<Foo>) criteria.list();
    session.delete(confirm.get(0)); //Works for single object, 
                                    //what about batching?
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Either you iterate over the entities and call delete for each of them, or you construct a delete query:

```
String hql = "delete from Foo f where f.id in :fooIds";
session.createQuery(hql).setParameterList("fooIds", fooIds).executeUpdate();
```

Make sure to understand the restrictions and caveats associated to such DML queries though. They're described in [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#batch-direct).

Comment: oh ok. i guess i'll have to use this way. i was wondering if i could directly delete using the list of objects. e.g., session.delete(obj).

Comment: if fooIds gets large, though, you're going to start running into problems with speed and potentially crashing.  if there is a way do to it with ```where exists``` or via a join it will scale better.

Comment: If you're using SQL Server, you'll need to batch those. Something like `fooIds.collate(1000).each { // operation  }`

Answer (score 3):

`String hql = "delete from Foo f where f.id in :fooIds";`
should be
`String hql = "delete from Foo f where f.id in (:fooIds)";`
or such exception would throw:
"Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: "
my hibernate version is 3.6.0.Final.